# build: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljsonrp-cpp

Tags: cmake

I am a cmake noob and I'm trying to debug a project from github with CMakeTools on vscode so that I can do some work based on it. However, The original project is https://github.com/s-vincent/jsonrpc-cpp.git. It has some examples to test on terminal, I tried the examples and they function well on terminal. Then I try to debug it and I wrote a `CMakelists.txt` to build it in vscode.
THis is my `CMakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.1)

project(tcp_examples)

find_package(jsoncpp CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(/home/zyd/Tool/jsonrpc-cpp/jsonrpc-cpp-master/include/) #includes from specific directories
include_directories(/home/zyd/Tool/jsonrpc-cpp/jsonrpc-cpp-master/src/) 
include_directories(/home/zyd/Tool/jsonrpc-cpp/jsonrpc-cpp-master/src/.libs) 
include_directories(/home/zyd/Tool/jsonrpc-cpp/jsonrpc-cpp-master/src/.deps) 

add_library(jsonrpc_client_cpp src/jsonrpc_client.cpp)
add_library(jsonrpc_handler_cpp src/jsonrpc_handler.cpp)
add_library(jsonrpc_httpclient_cpp src/jsonrpc_httpclient.cpp)
add_library(jsonrpc_server_cpp src/jsonrpc_server.cpp)
add_library(jsonrpc_tcpclient_cpp src/jsonrpc_tcpclient.cpp)
add_library(jsonrpc_tcpserver_cpp src/jsonrpc_tcpserver.cpp)
add_library(jsonrpc_udpclient_cpp src/jsonrpc_udpclient.cpp)
add_library(jsonrpc_udpserver_cpp src/jsonrpc_udpserver.cpp)
add_library(netstring_cpp src/netstring.cpp)
add_library(networking_cpp src/networking.cpp)
add_library(system_cpp src/system.cpp)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} examples/tcp-server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp_lib)   #link the library!
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsonrp-cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${jsoncpp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I googled everywhere and find nothing. Looks like -ljsonrp-ccp is not exist in this world. Is there something wrong with my `CMakelists.txt`?

Comment: "Is there something wrong with my `CMakelists.txt`?" - As you have almost correctly guessed, you are linking with a library `jsonrp-ccp` which doesn't exist at the locations, which are default locations for libraries. You need to specify path to that library. See the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) and its answers about linking with a library at the specific path.